# Favicon displaying in Firefox and not Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, favicon

My website is here: www.drizly.com

Our favicon shows up in Firefox but not in Chrome... I've read and tried everything, well, clearly not everything.  I don't get it.  Can someone help?

Comment: What file format is your favicon?  What is your favicon file called (e.g. favicon.ico)? Is it located in the root directory of your website?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `rel="shortcut icon"` and an absolute URL to your favicon.

Example:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong html structure, you missing open tag `<html>`.

Now i see:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome interprets this like:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<doctype! html="">

    <title>Drizly | Alcohol Delivery, Boston MA.</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://drizly.com/img/favicon.ico">
    ...
</body>
</html>
```